# Express $\frac{\partial^{2}z}{\partial r^{2}}$ in terms of r, $\theta$, and the partial derivative of f.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $z=f(x,y)$ and let r and $\theta$ be polar coordinates in the x-y plane.  Recall that $x=r \cos \theta$ and $y=r \sin \theta$.  Express $\frac{\partial^{2}z}{\partial r^{2}}$ in terms of r, $\theta$, and the partial derivative of f.

Letting

$$
g(x,y,\theta)=\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}
=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}
+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial r},
$$
$$
g(x,y,\theta)=f_{x} \cos \theta + f_{y} \sin \theta.
$$
So
$$
\frac{\partial^{2}z}{\partial r^{2}}=
\frac{\partial g}{\partial r}=
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}
+\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}
+\frac{\partial g}{\partial \theta}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial r}
$$

The last term vanishes so we get
$$
\frac{\partial^{2}z}{\partial r^{2}}=
(f_{xx}) \cos^{2} \theta +f_{yx}\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta}+ f_{xy} \sin{\theta}\cos{\theta}+(f_{yy})\sin^{2} \theta
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last step should be

$$\frac{\partial^{2}z}{\partial r^{2}}=
(f_{xx}) \cos^{2} \theta +f_{yx}\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta}+ f_{xy} \sin{\theta}\cos{\theta}+(f_{yy})\sin^{2} \theta$$

Answer (score 1):

Your final answer should be: $$f_{xx} \  \cos^2(\theta) +  f_{yy}  \  \sin^2(\theta) + (f_{xy} \  + \   f_{yx})  \ \sin(\theta) \ \cos(\theta) $$

The error was in your assumption that $\theta$ and $x,y$ are independent. They are not, since $x = r \cos(\theta)$ and $y = r \sin(\theta)$.